# save values to settings in stringcollection

Tags: vb.net

I want to save all the user input in textboxes to a stringcollection in settings
This is the code I have but it dont work and I cant figure out why?

```
  Sub LoadingData()
    '' add all textbox names here whose value you want to persist.
    For Each TBox() As TextBox In Me.Panel1.Controls
        With My.Settings
            If .savetxt Is Nothing Then .savetxt = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
            For i = 0 To TBox.Length - 1
                If .savetxt.Count <= i Then .savetxt.Add("")
                TBox(i).Text = .savetxt(i)
            Next
        End With

    Next
End Sub
Sub SavingData()
    For Each TBox() As TextBox In Me.Panel1.Controls
        For i = 0 To TBox.Length - 1
            My.Settings.savetxt(i) = TBox(i).Text
        Next
    Next
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: For every `TBox` found by the outer loop, `SavingData` overwrites `My.Settings.savetxt(i)` for all `i`. I guess the last `TBox` wins. Is that intentional?

Comment: HI Ruud I want to save all textboxes in my.settings using a loop

Comment: I would expect a single loop iterating through all textboxes within the panel. Please explain why you think you need a nested loop (i.e. a for-next within a for-next).

Comment: `For Each TBox() As TextBox (...)` should be `For Each TBox As TextBox In Me.Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)`. Each `TBox` is a single control, not an array. +  When loading back the values with this method, how do you know which string to assign to each TextBox.Text property? A random one is ok?

Comment: Hi Jimi thanks for the reply, I have over 200 textboxes in my form and I want to save them all when the form closes and load the user values back when the form opens.

Comment: What do you mean by "dont work"? Do you get an error? What is the error? Does it behave differently from what you expect? What does it do?

Comment: Hi Mary, I get an error on textbox.length -1 .Length not  a member of textbox

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a no code solution...

1. Go to the Form Designer. Select a TextBox.
2. In the Properties window select the plus sign to the left of (ApplicationSettings). (At the very top)
3. Click in the empty (PropertyBinding) box, click the ellipsis button (...).
4. Select the property, in this case Text. Click the drop down arrow; then the New...
5. Give the Setting a name, something simple but unique, perhaps t1 (then t2 for next TextBox and so on) Choose a Scope. Click OK and OK.

Your all set. A small icon will appear by the Text property in the Properties Window. Hoovering over this will tell you that the property is bound to a setting called t1. The Text property will be automatically saved and loaded.

Comment: HI Mary thanks for the reply, I know the the propertyBinding at design mode but Im looking for a code solution.